# SpiderMonkey shell. Is it possible to load shred library dynamicly?

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

Is it possible to load extension, built as shared library to SpiderMonkey's shell dynamicly (to stanalone shell, not in browser)? For example, Tcl has 'load' procedure to dynamicly load shared libraries. In SpiderMonkey's API there is function 'load', but it loads only script-files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you're looking for [jsctypes, which can do dlloads and make FFI wrappers](https://web.archive.org/web/20210528115949/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) for C functions exported from those DLLs.

It's also possible you're looking for something more like full-custom extension modules. You could write a builtin that dlloads a shared object, and grabs a symbol out of it that tells you what spidermonkey functions are contained therein and registers that bunch of functions. I don't recall any pre-canned way to do that -- SpiderMonkey was often extended in non-trivial ways by embedders, but it wasn't really a project priority to bake such things into the shell out of the box. Could always ask on #jsapi channel of irc.mozilla.org to double check!

Comment: That library now features a deprecation warning on its web page